# How to use atoi with an int and malloc?

Tags: c, pointers, malloc, atoi

When I try and use atoi with an int and malloc I get a bunch of errors and key is given the wrong value, what am I doing wrong?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct arguments {
    int key;
};

void argument_handler(int argc, char **argv, struct arguments *settings);

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    argv[1] = 101; //makes testing faster
    struct arguments *settings = (struct arguments*)malloc(sizeof(struct arguments));
    argument_handler(argc, argv, settings);
    free(settings);
    return 0;
}

void argument_handler(int argc, char **argv, struct arguments *settings) {
    int *key = malloc(sizeof(argv[1]));
    *key = argv[1];
    settings->key = atoi(key);
    printf("%d\n", settings->key);
    free(key);
}
```

Comment: most obvious thing you're doing that is odd/wrong is that `atoi` takes a `char *` as it's only parameter and you're passing it an `int *`

Comment: *"I get a bunch of errors"* - What errors?

Comment: Compile with all warnings enabled and consider them as errors.

Comment: although assigning `101` to `argv[1]` is also pretty weird...what is at memory location 101 that you think is a string?

Comment: Why use malloc in argument handler? Just do `settings->key = atoi(argv[1])` However, atoi is a function that should not be used (google why).

Comment: `argv[1] = 101;` makes no sense at all.

Comment: Tbh, this very short code is full with small details that proves that you need to go back pretty far and learn the basic concepts, like string handling and memory allocation.

Comment: @klutt I suppose `argument_handler` is still to elaborated.

Comment: When I compile this with `-Wall -Wextra` I get four warnings, which is a lot for such a short snippet. Activate warnings. Those four warnings are all things that points out flaws in your code, but there are more things too.

Comment: And [don't cast malloc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct arguments {
  int key;
};

void argument_handler(int argc, char** argv, struct arguments* settings);

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  argv[1] = "101";  // 101 is a string, therefore you need ""
  struct arguments* settings = (struct arguments*)malloc(sizeof(struct arguments));
  argument_handler(argc, argv, settings);
  free(settings);
  return 0;
}

void argument_handler(int argc, char** argv, struct arguments* settings) {
  char* key = malloc(strlen(argv[1]) + 1);  // you want the length of the string here,
                                            // and you want char* here, not int*

  strcpy(key, argv[1]);                    // string needs to be copied
  settings->key = atoi(key);
  printf("%d\n", settings->key);
  free(key);
}
```

But this is very awkward, actually the `argument_handler` can be rewritten like this:

```
void argument_handler(int argc, char** argv, struct arguments* settings) {
  settings->key = atoi(argv[1]);
  printf("%d\n", settings->key);
}
```

Disclaimer: I only corrected what was obviously wrong, there are still checks that need to be done, e.g. if `argc` is smaller than 2 etc.